# "Error processing request body" occurs randomly when sending image in expo/react-native

Tags: react-native, fetch, expo

I have recently been having a problem with the iOS version of the app I am developing. Often when sending an image to the server (selected utilizing the component expo-image-picker), it returns the error:

```
Error procession request body: Error Domain=ABI34_0_0RCTErrorDomain Code=0
"Invalid request token"
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid request token.}
```

This is the method sending the data:

```
alterUserDataOnDatabase(formValues, callback) {
        fetch(url , {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
            body: formValues
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => callback(responseJson));
}
```

And this is the code to get the image itself using image picker

```
_pickImage = async () => {
        const {
            status: cameraRollPerm
        } = await ImagePicker.getCameraRollPermissionsAsync();
        //await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);

        // only if user allows permission to camera roll
        if (cameraRollPerm === 'granted') {
            try {
                let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
                    allowsEditing: true,
                    aspect: [4, 4],
                });

                this._handleImagePicked(pickerResult);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        }
};

_handleImagePicked = async pickerResult => {
        try {
            this.setState({
                uploading: true
            });

            if (!pickerResult.cancelled) {
                let uri = pickerResult.uri;
                let uriParts = uri.split('.');
                let fileType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];

                this.form.append('photo', {
                    uri: uri,
                    name: `photo.${fileType}`,
                    type: `image/${fileType}`,
                });

                this.setState({
                    image: uri
                });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log({ e });
            alert('Upload failed, sorry :(');
        } finally {
            this.setState({
                uploading: false
            });
        }
};
```

I was using expo and react-native in its 34 version, I have tried them to the version 36, but it didn't do anything for it, the error merely changed from ABI34 to ABI36.

The error occurs only sometimes, which is the odd part, it seems to happen at random, but the usually, after sending one image, the next one will return the error, though sometimes it happens the first time I try to send.

Does anyone know anything about this error, I am having a hard time finding answers to it.

Edit: I have tried creating new, empty apps on expo, the code and packages works on the new app, but it doesn't seem to work with everything together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out how to fix it.

Before sending the data to the server, I was using `this.setState()` to start an animation in the app so the user can't press the button after already having sent the data (For this, I was using the component 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay').

For some reason, which I couldn't discern, updating the state in the frame as sending the form with an image will cause this error. To fix it, I simply put the method to send the data to the server on a `setTimeout` and made it wait 100 ms before being sent.